# Corrected Poisson's equation and the preferred time direction of the cosmological constant?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, cosmological-constant, diffeomorphism-invariance

So if I [correct](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0004037.pdf) (equation 2.6) the Poisson's equation with the cosmological constant. Then, I get

$$  \Delta \Phi = (4 \pi G_N) \rho - \Lambda \tag{1}$$

But when I think of this from the [Einstein-Hilbert action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action).

$$S = \int \frac{1}{2 \kappa}(R - 2 \Lambda) + L_M)\sqrt{-g} d^4 x \tag{2}$$

where $R$ is the Ricci curvature, $L_M$ is the Lagrangian of matter,  $\sqrt{-g}$ is the volume and  $\kappa$ is a constant.

It seems like I've given the cosmological constant term a preferred time direction when from $(2)$ to $(1)$. This makes me worry the correction term is not diffeomorphism invariant.

Can someone start with the Einstein-Hilbert action and derive the corrected Poisson equation with a cosmological constant while addressing the preferred time direction?

Comment: What do you mean by time direction of cosmological constant?